# VBA Combo Boxes dont "mind" my dynamic range choice

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I have defined a database with lists for combo boxes. On each column I have the various options to fill the combo boxes respectively. When I run my userform the first two combo boxes (Client and Product) show options just fine. Why would the other combo boxes all list Client options?

```js
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cClient As Range
Dim cProduct As Range
Dim cSize As Range
Dim cType As Range
Dim cTax As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("aux")

For Each cClient In ws.Range("ClientList")
  With Me.comboClient
    .AddItem cClient.Value
  End With
Next cClient

For Each cProduct In ws.Range("ProductList")
  With Me.comboProduct
    .AddItem cProduct.Value
  End With
Next cProduct

For Each cSize In ws.Range("ClientList")
  With Me.comboSize
    .AddItem cSize.Value
  End With
Next cSize

For Each cType In ws.Range("ClientList")
  With Me.comboType
  .AddItem cType.Value
  End With
Next cType

For Each cTax In ws.Range("ClientList")
  With Me.comboTax
    .AddItem cTax.Value
  End With
Next cTax

Me.textDate.Value = Format(Date, "Medium Date")
Me.textDate.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: This appears to be a simple typographical error, that you have copied/pasted code snippets and inadvertently forgot to change the named range to which each combobox refers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you fill those comboboxes with values from ClientList range. Try to fetch values from other ranges on your worksheet (e.g. `For Each cSize In ws.Range ("SizeList")`)